# Oracle SQL efficiently find not matching rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below tables t1 and t2 in respective order:

| CA | CAC |
| --- | --- |
| CA1 | CA1C1 |
| CA1 | CA1C2 |
| CA2 | CA2C1 |
| CA2 | CA2C2 |
| CA3 | CA3C1 |
| CA3 | CA3C2 |

| CA | CAC | MO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CA1 | CA1C1 | A99 |
| CA1 | CA1C2 | A99 |
| CA1 | CA1C3 | A00 |
| CA2 | CA2C1 | A99 |
| CA2 | CA2C2 | A99 |
| CA2 | CA2C3 | A00 |
| CA3 | CA3C1 | A99 |
| CA3 | CA3C2 | A99 |
| CA3 | CA3C3 | A99 |
| CA4 | CA4C1 | A99 |
| CA4 | CA4C2 | A00 |
| CA4 | CA4C3 | A00 |

I would like to find the entries from t2 whose CA is in t1 but have a CAC with a MO equal to 'A99' which is not present in t1.

The expected result should look like this:

| CA | CAC |
| --- | --- |
| CA3 | CA3C3 |

Please find the code to generate the data below:

```
with t1(ca, cac) as(
    select 'ca1', 'ca1c1' from dual union all
    select 'ca1', 'ca1c2' from dual union all
    select 'ca2', 'ca2c1' from dual union all
    select 'ca2', 'ca2c2' from dual union all
    select 'ca3', 'ca3c1' from dual union all
    select 'ca3', 'ca3c2' from dual
    )
,
t2(ca, cac, mo) as(
    select 'ca1', 'ca1c1', 'a99' from dual union all
    select 'ca1', 'ca1c2', 'a99' from dual union all
    select 'ca1', 'ca1c3', 'a00' from dual union all
    select 'ca1', 'ca1c1', 'a99' from dual union all
    select 'ca2', 'ca1c2', 'a99' from dual union all
    select 'ca2', 'ca1c3', 'a00' from dual union all
    select 'ca3', 'ca1c1', 'a99' from dual union all
    select 'ca3', 'ca1c2', 'a99' from dual union all
    select 'ca3', 'ca1c3', 'a99' from dual union all
    select 'ca4', 'ca1c1', 'a99' from dual union all
    select 'ca4', 'ca1c2', 'a00' from dual union all
    select 'ca4', 'ca1c3', 'a00' from dual
    )
select * from t1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If I follow correctly, this is filtering:

```
select t2.*
from t2
where t2.mo = 'a99' and
      exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.ca = t2.ca) and
      not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.cac = t2.cac);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a0fc4494910e3ff91345d980b9f66efb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! What would be the best approach if I needed to include one column related to ca in t1?

Comment: @JaviTorre . . . Please ask a new question.  And be explicit about how you want that column defined.